# SQL selecting specific entity from self associated entity set

Tags: sql, sqlite, entity, erd

I want to write a SQL statement that lists the details of all employees that work under a manager, from the following list of manager IDs: 7092, 7566, 7788.

I am just confused as to the one optional to many optional relationship an employee has with itself. Could someone please explain this?

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: How deep is the employee hierarchy?  What I mean by this is that, for example, could a manager himself have a manager?  I think you only need to involve the `Employee` table here.

Comment: someone please help, thanks

Comment: Why don't you answer the above question?

Comment: That is the `managerID`. Didn't you teacher explain this before he gave you the homework?

Comment: There are two teirs; Managers and employees who work under the manager. But I dont understand, how do you identify managers and employees? 

Also, why is the managerID attribute a Foreign Key?